# "Counter-example" to closed graph theorem

Tags: general-topology, continuity, examples-counterexamples

The closed graph theorem states that the graph of a continuous function from any space $X$ to the Huasdorff space $Y$ is closed, as stated in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108709/is-the-graph-g-f-x-fx-in-x-times-y-x-in-x-a-closed-subset-of-x) MSE question.

But the graph of $f: (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $\sin(1/x)$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$, because it does not equal its closure.

Why is this not  a counter-example?

Comment: $Y$ must be a compact Hausdorff space

Comment: @Analysis https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108709/is-the-graph-g-f-x-fx-in-x-times-y-x-in-x-a-closed-subset-of-x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct statement is that the graph of a continuous function $f: X \to Y$, where $Y$ is Hausdorff, is closed **in $X \times Y$**.   The graph in your example is closed in $(0,\infty) \times \mathbb R$, though not in $\mathbb R^2$.